# Passing a List element in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

Attempting a text adventure game. Visual Studios 2019, Console application.

I have an Room class as such

```
  public class Room
    {
        public string name;
        public string description;
        public int roomNumber;
        public int lightLevel;
        public int trap;
        public int flag1;
        public int flag2;
        public int north;
        public int northeast;
        public int east;
        public int southeast;
        public int south;
        public int southwest;
        public int west;
        public int northwest;
        public int up;
        public int down;
    }
```

and a text file with the Room data.

```
{front street}
{standing in a dirt road.} 
{1 10 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}
{front street}
{standing on a dirt road on the edge of town.}
{2 10 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0}
```

I have 112 rooms (or blocks) which is read into a list. I plan to expand this list to about 400 rooms or so. I need to pass some rooms around to a few different methods. I can pass the entire list, that doesn't strike me as a good idea. That's a lot of data to pass, and understand gremlins find their way in lots of excess data. I can pass a single element as so...

```
PrintRoom(ref rooms[currentRoom].name);
```

But I can't seem to find the right syntax to pass a single room. I would like to pass one room/block at a time. Actually, I only need the last ten elements, to determine if the player can go in a certain direction or not, but I think for all the work, it'd be easier to pass the entire room.
So what is the proper syntax to pass a single room (or block)?
What would the header on the function look like please?

I thank you in advance.

Comment: `PrintRoom(rooms[currentRoomIndex]);`? Of course, the `PrintRoom()` method would need to accept a parameter of type `Room` (e.g., `public void PrintRoom(Room roomToPrint) { string name = roomToPrint.name; // more code }`. And FYI, you don't need the `ref` keyword here because `Room` is a class, which is a reference type.

Comment: you need to write the getter and setter to set or get the values of these parameters. Once you do that, you can use .name or .attrib

Comment: I already use those.

Answer (score 1):

If you read these into a list, why not try using LINQ? You could use a lambda expression to get what you need, and with this approach it would allow you more flexibility if you ever wanted to project into an object that had more than a single property, but less than the entire collection of properties.

```
public class LinqExample
{
    public void LinqMethod()
    {
        var rooms = new List<Room> 
        { 
            new Room
            {
                name = "roomA",
                description = "Desc Abc",
                roomNumber = 1,
                // etc
            },
            new Room
            {
                name = "roomB",
                description = "Desc Def",
                roomNumber = 1,
                // etc
            }
        };

        var room = rooms.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "roomB");

        PassRoomExample(room);
    
    }

    public void PassRoomExample(Room room)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"name: { room.name }, Description: { room.description }, Room #: {room.roomNumber}");
    }
}
```